# Как разрешить конфликт обновление Symfony 3.3 на Symfony 4?

Tags: composer, symfony3, php7

Пытаюсь обновить Symfony 3 на Symfony 4:

```
composer update symfony/symfony
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
      Problem 1
        - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.3.14
        - Conclusion: remove sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.21
        - Conclusion: don't install sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.21
        - Installation request for sensio/distribution-bundle == 5.0.21.0 -> satisfiable by sensio/distribution-bundle[v5.0.21].
        - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.0.1
        - sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.21 requires symfony/process 
          ~2.3|~3.0 -> 
           satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.14],
           symfony/process[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10,
           v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14,
           v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, 
           v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21,
           v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.
```

Так как 4 версия стала стабильной недавно, подскажите пожалуйста, как разрешить конфликт?

Comment: Написано `SensioDistributionBundle

WARNING: This bundle does not support Symfony 4. Symfony Flex is a total replacement for this bundle.` Меняйте его на Symfony Flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Никак**. В комментарии было правильно описано, что нужно переходить на symfony-flex.

В репозитории SensioDistributionBundle написано:

> WARNING: This bundle does not support Symfony 4. Symfony Flex is a total replacement for this bundle.

Прочитайте подробнее про symfony-flex

- [Документация на оф.сайте](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html)
- [Репозиторий на github](https://github.com/symfony/flex)

Answer (score 0):

На Symfony 4 можно перейти без использования Symfony Flex. Для этого из composer.json надо удалить sensio/distribution-bundle, после чего выполнить

```
composer update
```

либо

```
composer update "symfony/*" --with-all-dependencies
```

если не нужно обновлять все остальные зависимости.

Если будет ругаться на залоченную версию какой-то зависимости - можно временно удалить файл composer.lock

После перехода на Symfony 4 можно по желанию установить Symfony Flex. При этом это возможно сделать и в обратной последовательности, как душе угодно, т.к. Symfony Flex совместим с Symfony 3.4

И вот еще с сайта Symfony:
"Using Symfony Flex is optional, even in Symfony 4, where Flex is used by default"
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html#upgrading-existing-applications-to-flex

Т.е. Symfony Flex рекомендуется, но не является обязательным для Symfony 4.